# Maui framework doesn't display sliders correctly

Tags: slider, maui

I have been dipping my toes in the .NET Maui framework, but unfortunately so far it has been quite disappointing. There seem to be multiple errors related to Shell (title view not working properly) and controls themselves. I have the following main page xaml file:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Background="#111111" >
        <Frame HasShadow="True" Margin="10" CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="#222222">
            <StackLayout Spacing="30">
                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="30,*">
                    <Label Text="R" FontSize="Medium"  TextColor="White" />
                    <Slider GridLayout.Column="1" MinimumTrackColor="Red" ThumbColor="Red" MaximumTrackColor="#AAAAAA" />
                </Grid>
                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="30,*">
                    <Label Text="G" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" />
                    <Slider GridLayout.Column="1" MinimumTrackColor="#7FFF00" ThumbColor="#7FFF00" MaximumTrackColor="#AAAAAA" />
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

which is just a stack layout with a single frame that houses two sliders with labels. However, the two sliders seem to have a predefined width, as they are not filling the remaining space:
[image]

As soon as I add anything to any of the controls in the xaml while the app is running, for example a green background to the first grid, both sliders resize to the correct size:

[image]

However, when I reload the application with this change, the sliders go back to the wrong size:

[image]

There are additional issues that I encountered as well, when placing this content page as a flyout item in the shell where android behaviour was as described here, but additionally the Sliders are not interactable in Windows version. In this example with a clean project they do work in Windows version.

Comment: MAUI is still in **pre-release**.  Why do people act surprised that there are bugs and incomplete features?

Comment: Well, when trying it out I didn't expect to encounter bugs on the first two things that I have tried - populating Shell.TitleView and using Sliders. It is fairly basic stuff that I'd expect to work now. And I am asking because I'd like to know whether I am the only one with this issue thus suggesting some error on my side, or if it's just a bug.

Comment: the issues repo is public, and you're encouraged to report issues that you encounter

Comment: I experience something similar. Should probably report this to the .net maui team if it hasn't already

Comment: I did report it already, no need to do it again.

Answer (score -1):

Try with any third-party packages like [syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/maui-controls/maui-slider), etc. to meet your requirements.